# DVI monitor detected only on computer startup

Tags: windows, windows-xp, display, amd-radeon

I've recently connected a new monitor, LG M2252D-PZ, to a rather outdated computer with Windows XP and Radeon 9600. XP has SP3 installed, video drivers are the latest version back from the times the video card was still supported.

My problem is that the monitor works fine only as long as I don't turn it off or switch it to a different input. When I turn it back on, it says "no signal".

The key to the problem must be the DVI port, to which the new monitor is connected. The previous monitor was connected to the VGA output, and I've tested that the new one also works fine when connected to the analogue port.

Apparently, the computer tests for the presence of a monitor on the DVI port only on startup. The question is, how do I change this?